# How to use an event listener click function to display and hide images within an array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, event-listener

So I need to have a promo image displayed as a banner on a page.  I have 4 buttons underneath said banner.  Each button corresponds with a different promo image banner.

I would like to use an `eventlistener` with the click function to display each corresponding image, but only one at a time. This is the javascript I tried to use but doesn't seem to be working.

```js
var btn1 = document.getElementById("promo_button1");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("promo_button2");
var btn3 = document.getElementById("promo_button3");
var btn4 = document.getElementById("promo_button4");

var img1 = document.getElementById("promo1");
var img2 = document.getElementById("promo2");
var img3 = document.getElementById("promo3");
var img4 = document.getElementById("promo4");

var imgArray = [img1, img2, img3, img4];

function showImg(img) {
  for (i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
    imgArray[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  img.style.display = "block";
}


btn1.addEventListener("click", function() {
  showImg(img1);
});
btn2.addEventListener("click", function() {
  showImg(img2);
});
btn3.addEventListener("click", function() {
  showImg(img3);
});
btn4.addEventListener("click", function() {
  showImg(img4);
});
```

```html
<div class="section group">
  <div class="col span_1_of_6">
  </div>
  <div class="col span_4_of_6">
    <div class="promo" id="promo1">
      <a href="cat_suits.html" border="0"><img src="img/banner_suits.jpg" alt="Suits on sale!" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="promo" id="promo2" style="display:none">
      <a href="cat_suits.html" border="0"><img src="img/banner_shoes.jpg" alt="Shoes on sale!" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="promo" id="promo3" style="display:none">
      <a href="cat_suits.html" border="0"><img src="img/banner_shirts.jpg" alt="Shirts on sale!" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="promo" id="promo4" style="display:none">
      <a href="cat_suits.html" border="0"><img src="img/banner_pants.jpg" alt="Pants on sale!" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_6">
  </div>

  <div class="section group">
    <div class="col span_1_of_6">
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_6">
      <a href="">
        <div class="promo_button" id="promo_button1">
          Suits
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_6">
      <a href="">
        <div class="promo_button" id="promo_button2">
          Shoes
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_6">
      <a href="">
        <div class="promo_button" id="promo_button3">
          Shirts
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_6">
      <a href="">
        <div class="promo_button" id="promo_button4">
          Pants
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_6">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you building a carousel? You might be better off using a third party library that supports it rather than building your own.

Comment: No it's actually for a web design class I'm taking.  And not a carousel per say, just displaying different promos for each button on the main page.  We have to grab the element by id, then create an array for the images, then use a for loop and event listeners to change the image so that it corresponds with each button.

Comment: Added alot of code comments to explain my answer. If anything is unclear, ask!

Comment: Added a second snippet that even creates the buttons dynamically so you don't have to take care of that. Each button is labelled with the alt text of the corresponding img.

Comment: Let me know if my answer helped you getting into Javascript, or if is way too farr of what you feel you can understand based on your current level of knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well your code is working just fine, it is just the the `a` you have wrapping all the `<div class="promo_button"` has a blank `href=""` which is causing this issue.

So instead of keeping `href=""` which is causing a page redirection you should have `href="#"` and `onclick` of it you can just `return false`.

```js
var btn1 = document.getElementById("promo_button1");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("promo_button2");
var btn3 = document.getElementById("promo_button3");
var btn4 = document.getElementById("promo_button4");

var img1 = document.getElementById("promo1");
var img2 = document.getElementById("promo2");
var img3 = document.getElementById("promo3");
var img4 = document.getElementById("promo4");

var imgArray = [img1, img2, img3, img4];

function showImg(img) {
  for (i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
    imgArray[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  img.style.display = "block";
}


btn1.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  showImg(img1);
});
btn2.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  showImg(img2);
});
btn3.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  showImg(img3);
});
btn4.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  showImg(img4);
});
```

```html
<div class="section group">
  <div class="col span_1_of_6">
  </div>
  <div class="col span_4_of_6">
    <div class="promo" id="promo1">
      <a href="cat_suits.html" border="0"><img src="img/banner_suits.jpg" alt="Suits on sale!" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="promo" id="promo2" style="display:none">
      <a href="cat_suits.html" border="0"><img src="img/banner_shoes.jpg" alt="Shoes on sale!" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="promo" id="promo3" style="display:none">
      <a href="cat_suits.html" border="0"><img src="img/banner_shirts.jpg" alt="Shirts on sale!" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="promo" id="promo4" style="display:none">
      <a href="cat_suits.html" border="0"><img src="img/banner_pants.jpg" alt="Pants on sale!" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_6">
  </div>

  <div class="section group">
    <div class="col span_1_of_6">
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_6">
      <a href="#" onclick="return false;">
        <div class="promo_button" id="promo_button1">
          Suits
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_6">
      <a href="#" onclick="return false;">
        <div class="promo_button" id="promo_button2">
          Shoes
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_6">
      <a href="#" onclick="return false;">
        <div class="promo_button" id="promo_button3">
          Shirts
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_6">
      <a href="#"  onclick="return false;">
        <div class="promo_button" id="promo_button4">
          Pants
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_6">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I haven't been on here for a few days.  What does the onclick="return false;" exactly do?

Comment: @bexter it will stop the default event from happening. That is page redirection. Does this code indent to do what you are expecting?

Comment: So my function I created was fine?  It was just the empty anchor tags.  Interesting.

Comment: Still not working on my local drive.  not sure why.  Thanks for your help though

Comment: I realized I was missing a squiggly bracket after the for loop on my computer, haha. Got it working now!  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

First I have reduced your code to what we call an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on StackOverflow (I stripped all code that was not directly related to the problem).

Second I got rid of all `id` attributes you used, they are not needed.

Third, so something can be seen I replaced your local img urls by placeholder bears.

This is what I would come up with:

```js
// create an array holding the img DOM objects
let images = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.promo'));

// create an array from the buttons and iterate over it, 
// passing each button (as btn) and the index (as index)
// into each iteration
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.promo_button')).forEach((btn, index) => {
  // add a click event listener to the button
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // on click of a button, iterate over the images
    images.forEach((img, idx) => {
      // change style property of img to 
      // - none if the index of the image does not
      //   match the index of the button clicked
      // - block if both indexes match
      img.style.display = (index === idx ? 'block' : 'none');
      // using a ternary expression, which does the same as
      // if (index === idx) {
      //   img.style.display = 'block';
      // } else {
      //   img.style.display = 'none';
      // }
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<img src="https://placebear.com/200/300" alt="bear 1" class="promo" />
<img src="https://placebear.com/300/300" alt="bear 2" class="promo" style="display:none" />
<img src="https://placebear.com/300/200" alt="bear 3" class="promo" style="display:none" />
<img src="https://placebear.com/200/200" alt="bear 4" class="promo" style="display:none" />
<hr />
<button class="promo_button">Suits</button>
<button class="promo_button">Shoes</button>
<button class="promo_button">Shirts</button>
<button class="promo_button">Pants</button>
```

This very same Javascript would also work for an arbitrary number of images and the corresponding number of buttons. It would be even more elegant adding the buttons programmatically:

```js
let images = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.promo'));

// for each image, create a button to show it
// and outright attach the click handler to each button
images.forEach((img, index) => {
  let btn = document.createElement('button');
  let btnText = document.createTextNode(img.getAttribute('alt'));
  btn.appendChild(btnText);
  btn.classList.add('promo_button');
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    images.forEach((img, idx) => {
      img.style.display = (index === idx ? 'block' : 'none');
    })
  })
  document.body.append(btn);
})
```

```html
<img src="https://placebear.com/200/300" alt="bear 1" class="promo" />
<img src="https://placebear.com/300/300" alt="bear 2" class="promo" style="display:none" />
<img src="https://placebear.com/300/200" alt="bear 3" class="promo" style="display:none" />
<img src="https://placebear.com/200/200" alt="bear 4" class="promo" style="display:none" />
<hr />
```

### Edit

I just saw you're doing this for a webdesign class. Depending on the knowledge of your teacher this Javascript code might be too advanced for them. If you need any more explanations as of what's going on in line ... just ask.

Comment: Yeah, so for the class we just have to use eventlisteners to reference each button and get all the images and buttons by their IDs.  Then are supposed to use an array for the images I believe.  He said there should only be one function for the assignment.  I just didn't know if I was doing the function part correctly. And apparently need to do something about my empty anchor tags

Comment: Thank you though!  I'm sure this would be more applicable in the real world (unfortunately not in my class), so I appreciate you explaining everything

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default action of the anchor tag, writing the anchor `href=""` is not correct. You can make use of `href="javascript:void(0);"`

The reason you’d want to do this with the href of a link is that normally, a `javascript:` URL will redirect the browser to a plain text version of the result of evaluating that JavaScript. But if the result is `undefined`, then the browser stays on the same page. `void(0)` is just a short and simple script that evaluates to `undefined`.

```js
var btn1 = document.getElementById("promo_button1");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("promo_button2");
var btn3 = document.getElementById("promo_button3");
var btn4 = document.getElementById("promo_button4");

var img1 = document.getElementById("promo1");
var img2 = document.getElementById("promo2");
var img3 = document.getElementById("promo3");
var img4 = document.getElementById("promo4");

var imgArray = [img1, img2, img3, img4];

function showImg(img) {
  for (i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
    imgArray[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  img.style.display = "block";
}


btn1.addEventListener("click", function() {
  showImg(img1);
});
btn2.addEventListener("click", function() {
  showImg(img2);
});
btn3.addEventListener("click", function() {
  showImg(img3);
});
btn4.addEventListener("click", function() {
  showImg(img4);
});
```

```html
<div class="section group">
  <div class="col span_1_of_6">
  </div>
  <div class="col span_4_of_6">
    <div class="promo" id="promo1">
      <a href="cat_suits.html" border="0"><img src="img/banner_suits.jpg" alt="Suits on sale!" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="promo" id="promo2" style="display:none">
      <a href="cat_suits.html" border="0"><img src="img/banner_shoes.jpg" alt="Shoes on sale!" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="promo" id="promo3" style="display:none">
      <a href="cat_suits.html" border="0"><img src="img/banner_shirts.jpg" alt="Shirts on sale!" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="promo" id="promo4" style="display:none">
      <a href="cat_suits.html" border="0"><img src="img/banner_pants.jpg" alt="Pants on sale!" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_6">
  </div>

  <div class="section group">
    <div class="col span_1_of_6">
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_6">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <div class="promo_button" id="promo_button1">
          Suits
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_6">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <div class="promo_button" id="promo_button2">
          Shoes
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_6">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <div class="promo_button" id="promo_button3">
          Shirts
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_6">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <div class="promo_button" id="promo_button4">
          Pants
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_6">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial problem was in your HTML with the anchor tag surrounding the .promo_button elements. The anchor tag's href attribute was set to an empty string, "".

A few suggestions: I would avoid putting inline styles in you HTML as much as possible because they can be difficult to locate as your project grows. Also document.querySelector and  document.querySelectorAll are a better solution than document.getElementByXXX when you need to reference a group of related HTML elements. Since document.querySelectorAll assigns the items to a NodeList array, you can access each element without having to assign IDs in HTML or individual variable names in JavaScript. You can do the same with HTMLCollections, but their limitations are greater in my opinion.

```js
/*Assign .promo_button elements to a NodeList(Array-like)*/
var btn_list = document.querySelectorAll('.promo_button');


/*Assign .promo elements to a NodeList(Array-like)*/
var img_list = document.querySelectorAll('.promo');


/*Displays image associated with button pressed, hides other images
  Assumes image and its corresponding button will be at same index
*/
function showImg() {
  //for...of is ES6, a simple forloop can also do the trick but requires more code
  //.entries allows you to access key/value pairs of the NodeList
  for (var [index, btn] of btn_list.entries()) {
    img_list[index].style.display = "none";
    if (btn == document.activeElement) {
      img_list[index].style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
}

/*Assign click listener to .promo_button elements*/
for (btn of btn_list) {
  btn.onclick = showImg;
}
```

```css
.promo {
  display: none;
  /*hides all images when page loads*/
  border: 0;
}


/*displays first image when page loads*/

.promo:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: block;
}


/*sets fixed dimensions on images*/

.promo a img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 60px;
}

.promo_button {
  min-width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- HTML CHANGES: added links to image tag's src attribute, removed inline styles  -->  
  
<div class="section group">
  <div class="col span_1_of_6">
  </div>
  <div class="col span_4_of_6">
    <div class="promo" id="promo1">
      <a href="cat_suits.html" ><img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/unrecognizable-businessman-in-a-classical-suit-picture-id496312478?k=6&m=496312478&s=612x612&w=0&h=wV0lxNsnG6XMW4uIKL89HQD3A9LNFKhalhpb05auVR0=" alt="Suits on sale!" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="promo" id="promo2">
      <a href="cat_suits.html" ><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcStxa8Lo2sWRpgR2klGQiR_YeLtumUBaSdCWHQNw1ciOdiP1HBAEw" alt="Shoes on sale!" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="promo" id="promo3">
      <a href="cat_suits.html" ><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSKKe0BOy0ulsoKUMo6DyHXBdoomNx_ZH7aCTsX-QS2Ilo0uPO5" alt="Shirts on sale!" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="promo" id="promo4">
      <a href="cat_suits.html" ><img src="https://thumb1.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/2746450/512816923/stock-photo-brown-pants-512816923.jpg" alt="Pants on sale!" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_6">
  </div>
 
  <!-- HTML CHANGES: Added button tags instead of div tags, remove IDs, added dead link(#) to Anchor tags to prevent leaving page when button clicked  -->
  
  <div class="section group">
    <div class="col span_1_of_6">
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_6">
      <a href="#">
        <button class="promo_button" >
          Suits
        </button>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_6">
      <a href="#">
        <button class="promo_button" >
          Shoes
        </button>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_6">
      <a href="#">
        <button class="promo_button" >
          Shirts
        </button>
      <!-- </a> -->
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_6">
      <a href="#">
        <button class="promo_button">
          Pants
        </button>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_6">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```